# How to link urls in firefox textbox

Tags: javascript, firefox

Heloo i have this code to give me a current url and title. If i click the button it gives me `<a href="https://developer.mozilla.org/cs/">Mozilla Developer Center - MDN</a>`
how can I get only the title as link?

```
   // Show Current Open URL
    function CurrentOpenURL()
    {
    // clears the field of textbox when clicked other button
    document.getElementById('MyExtension').value=''; 

    var textbox = document.getElementById("MyExtension");

    var title = getBrowser().contentTitle ;
    var url = getBrowser().currentURI.spec;

    textbox.value =  title.link(url);
```

Comment: You have:
textbox.value =  title.link(url);

Wouldn't you want:
textbox.value =  title;

Comment: yes but its not clickable :( its only text

Comment: Wait, let me make sure i got this right, you want to make a textbox clickable like an a tag?

Comment: yes? i want that title only there as link to the current url

Comment: then you need to add an onclick action with javascript or Jquery:

document.getElementById("MyExtension").setAttribute('onclick', 'window.location(' + url + ')');

Answer (score 0):

With this regex you will replace the html tags

```
var title = url.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");
```

You dont need jQuery for this.

Comment: noo still the same..stil is there the a href and ist not clickable :( but thx for helping me